# How can I display a return in three columns (in Google Apps Script) that looks like an array, but (to me) doesn't behave like one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

How can I display this return in three columns **on my web app**, preferably with given headers?

**THIS IS PROBABLY IMPORTANT!**
According to the writer of the **gvizQuery** function, which I use to find data in a referenced Google Sheet, ***the return is an array of arrays***.

The code runs Google Apps Script V8.

This is the simplest version of the code where I provide a serial number, which is sent to the query function, and returned along with a reference to ou and most recent user.

```js
document.getElementById("btnserno1").addEventListener("click",fetchCBOU);
    function fetchCBOU(){
        var sernum = document.getElementById("serial").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(printCBOUU)
        .queryCBOU(sernum);
    }
        window.printCBOUU = function(CBOUU) {
        console.log(CBOUU);
        var CBOU1 = CBOUU

        document.getElementById('idCB').innerHTML = CBOU1[0];
        document.getElementById('idCBOU').innerHTML = CBOU1[1];
        document.getElementById('idCBRecent').innerHTML = CBOU1[2];
  }
```

In the *Stackdriver logs* the return is displayed like this.

Feb 17, 2020, 12:07:22 AM   Info    [[[5CD725B5B0, /Grundskolor/Boras, utd8377@edu.kunskapsskolan.se]]]

This is what it looks like in the console.
First a perfect match.

[image: Perfect match]

On the web app it displays the three values in one place, and leaves the other two as *undefined*.
[image: displays on web app]

If I instead do a partial match, I get more arrays in console.

[image: partial match]

But in the web app I get all those values in the first element and the two other elements are still *undefined*.

If I manipulate the incoming data after it arrives, and try split it up, I get different results depending on if it's a perfect or partial match.

I changed the middle part of the code to this.

```js
        window.printCBOUU = function(CBOUU) {
        console.log(CBOUU);        

        //Creating the new variable, based off CBOUU, adding quotation marks.
        var str = CBOUU + '';
        console.log(str);

        //Creating the new array, based off CBOUU, and now, since it has quotation marks, it becomes an array.
        var CBOU1 = str.split(",");
        console.log(CBOU1);

        document.getElementById('idCB').innerHTML = CBOU1[0];
        document.getElementById('idCBOU').innerHTML = CBOU1[1];
        document.getElementById('idCBRecent').innerHTML = CBOU1[2];
  }
```

For a perfect match and a partial match that only has a single matching device everything still works.

[image: exact & partial single match works]

But if I do a partial match and get many hits everything breaks, as it is no longer working with variables with three sets of data, but instead as many values as there are matching devices, times three values. And to display them I'd have to keep adding CBOU1[n] values for each one.

[image]

**Do note that this is not static data! I'm trying to display the return from a function where I search for a partial serial number from a Google sheet.**

**Logs** (I thought this was an array, with three values for each object, but apparently this could be an array of arrays)

`[20-02-14 16:28:16:153 CET] [[[5CD9264KBW, /Grundskolor/Boras, user1@my.domain], [5CD9264K64, /Grundskolor/Boras, user2@my.domain], [5CD9264K7V, /Grundskolor/Boras, user3@my.domain], [5CD9264K6M, /Grundskolor/Boras, user4@my.domain]]`

**Console** after I try to turn it into a usable array (here it looks to me to be a single array of only one object, with a bunch of values)

`["5CD9264KBW", "/Grundskolor/Boras", "user1@my.domain", "5CD9264K64", "/Grundskolor/Boras", "user2@my.domain", "5CD9264K7V", "/Grundskolor/Boras", "user3@my.domain", "5CD9264K6M", "/Grundskolor/Boras", "user4@my.domain"]`

Comment: @TheMaster, that's from the _View_ menu (Ctrl-Enter). After I run a search for a serial, the return data is displayed in Logs.

Thanks for the correction of my question, btw.

Comment: Yes, it's a web app. Runs query on sheet and returns data like it shows in Logs. I then try to display that data in three columns (in a table or as three <li> values, which ever is possible) on the web app page.

I have the base code published here. https://github.com/NoSubstitute/CB_LookUp

But page-js doesn't contain above code yet, as it doesn't work. I only have it in my dev.

This is what old code looks like with one match (not same code as above).
I would like to have more matches listed below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o3ahsvkMFPpBaU9DwUYdTBhmEywn-KqQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you do a console.log of the dynamic data? Because the static data on Coopers response is a String and not an array. That might be the error.

Comment: Hi, @Kessy 

That's what you see in the beginning of my discription of the problem.
The two images with black background show console.log result with single match and multiple matches.

What I, and maybe others may have, missed is that the result in console.log is an Array of Arrays. So maybe we're attacking it incorrectly.

My latest thought was that perhaps the original dynamic return needs a nested for-loop (two loops) to deconstruct the data, instead of manipulating it, like I do further down.

Comment: Updated the later half of the question with successful progress.

My final issue is how to align my table headers with the data. Currently the headers are in a separate table, which is why they aren't affected. If I put them in the same table creation process, weird things happen.

Comment: Don't answer your question in your question-that makes it hard to read and understand what the actual problem was, and what the solution is. Instead, write an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, @tehhowch!
I'm still learning how to navigate this place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to my question. As suggested, I have now put it in a separate answer, as to not confuse the solution with the question.
Changed the table code a bit, so I could move the idCBS to where it didn't interfere with the headers.

Updated page.html.

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th><h6>Serial</h6></th>
      <th><h6>Device OU</h6></th>
      <th><h6>Most Recent User</h6></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody id="idCBS">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Columns now align!

Here's the updated page-js.html.

```
 document.getElementById("btnserno").addEventListener("click",fetchCBS);
    function fetchCBS(){
        document.getElementById("idCBS").innerHTML = "";
        var sernum = document.getElementById("serial").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(printCBS)
        .queryCBS(sernum);
        document.getElementById("serial").value = "";
    }

    window.printCBS = function(CBS) {
    
    var i,innerArray;
    var L = CBS[0].length;
  
    for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    innerArray = CBS[0][i];
  
    value1 = innerArray[0]; 
    value2 = innerArray[1];
    value3 = innerArray[2];          

    let html='<style>td,th{border:0px solid black;}</style><table>';
    html+='<tr><td>' + value1 + '</td><td>' + value2 + '</td><td>' + value3 + '</td></tr>';
    html+='</table>';
    
    var myTable = document.getElementById("idCBS");
    myTable.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  
    }
}

//Code for the clearResults button
document.getElementById("clearResults").addEventListener("click",clrResults);
function clrResults(){
    document.getElementById("idCBS").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitItUp() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data='[[[5CD9264KBW, /Grundskolor/Boras, user1@my.domain], [5CD9264K64, /Grundskolor/Boras, user2@my.domain], [5CD9264K7V, /Grundskolor/Boras, user3@my.domain], [5CD9264K6M, /Grundskolor/Boras, user4@my.domain]]';
  var a=data.slice(3,-2).trim().replace(/\], \[/g,'~~~').split('~~~');
  var b=[];
  a.forEach(function(r){b.push(r.split(', '));});
  sh.getRange(1,1,b.length,b[0].length).setValues(b);                                      
}
```

I'm guessing that you can take it from here:

```
function splitItUp() {
  const data='[[[5CD9264KBW, /Grundskolor/Boras, user1@my.domain], [5CD9264K64, /Grundskolor/Boras, user2@my.domain], [5CD9264K7V, /Grundskolor/Boras, user3@my.domain], [5CD9264K6M, /Grundskolor/Boras, user4@my.domain]]';
  let a=data.slice(3,-2).trim().replace(/\], \[/g,'~~~').split('~~~');
  let b=[];
  a.forEach(function(r){b.push(r.split(', '));});
  let html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>'; 
  b.forEach(function(r,i){html+=`<tr><td>${r[0]}</td><td>${r[1]}</td><td>${r[2]}</td></tr>`;});
  html+='</table>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Split It Up')                                     
}
```

I just put it into a dialog since I don't have a web app handy right now.

Okay maybe this is what you want.

```
function splitItUp() {
  const data='[[[5CD9264KBW, /Grundskolor/Boras, user1@my.domain], [5CD9264K64, /Grundskolor/Boras, user2@my.domain], [5CD9264K7V, /Grundskolor/Boras, user3@my.domain], [5CD9264K6M, /Grundskolor/Boras, user4@my.domain]]';
  let a=data.slice(3,-2).trim().replace(/\], \[/g,'~~~').split('~~~');
  let b=[];
  a.forEach(function(r){b.push(r.split(', '));});
  let html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>'; 
  b.forEach(function(r,i){html+=`<tr><td>${r[0]}</td><td>${r[1]}</td><td>${r[2]}</td></tr>`;});
  html+='</table>';
  //var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Split It Up')
  document.getElementByID('iddeviceInfo').innerHTML=html;
}
```

Okay here's an example of a small webapp.  I actually ran it as a dialog.

The html:(file name was ah1.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function(){
    splitItUp();
  });
  function splitItUp() {
    const data='[[[5CD9264KBW, /Grundskolor/Boras, user1@my.domain], [5CD9264K64, /Grundskolor/Boras, user2@my.domain], [5CD9264K7V, /Grundskolor/Boras, user3@my.domain], [5CD9264K6M, /Grundskolor/Boras, user4@my.domain]]';
    let a=data.slice(3,-2).trim().replace(/\], \[/g,'~~~').split('~~~');
    let b=[];
    a.forEach(function(r){b.push(r.split(', '));});
    let html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>'; 
    b.forEach(function(r,i){html+=`<tr><td>${r[0]}</td><td>${r[1]}</td><td>${r[2]}</td></tr>`;});
    html+='</table>';
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=html;
  }  
  console.log('My Code');
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the gs: (for launching it as a dialog)

```
function runOne() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'), 'Data');
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to set it to the sheet. I'm trying to display it in the web app. And I can't write the values manually, as they are coming in a return from the function.

Comment: Hmmm, looking at your second attempt...
Doesn't that require I am looking at the result on the sheet?
The user accessing the web app does/will not have the sheet visible.

Comment: Yeah, [as I explained in my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249272/how-can-i-display-a-return-in-three-columns-in-google-apps-script-that-looks-l#comment106575510_60249272) on TheMaster's questions all of this takes place in a web app. The sheet isn't visible, only accessed by the web app in the background.

Comment: Well I gave you an array with all the data in it I presume that you know something about html and javascript so what's the problem?

Comment: Apparently I don't know enough. The array isn't in my code written visibly like that.
It's returned in the variable CBOUU, which if I exchange your code to start like this.

`const data = CBOUU;`

I will immediately get an error that says

`Uncaught TypeError: data.slice(...).trim is not a function`

and even if that ran I wouldn't know what to do with the result of the b.forEach function.

Basically, you're using too little of my current code for me to understand your answer. I can't convert your references to the spreadsheet to my web app.

Comment: Do you have V8 enabled?

Comment: Where do you want to put the table?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I have an image of what it looks like when I get an exact match (and don't use the query to get partial matches), and I'd like it to look similar when I do use query and get many matches.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o3ahsvkMFPpBaU9DwUYdTBhmEywn-KqQ/view?usp=sharing

Now, the exact match uses a different function than the partial match, and so the return is very different. It only returns three separate values, and as such is very easy to place. When I switched to a query, the return is only one value, with three data parts in it, which I then split.

Comment: No, as I'm not confident enough with GAS at all, I haven't enabled V8. Perhaps that is recommended going forward? I see the button suggesting it when I load my gas.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't follow links off of this site any longer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207947/discussion-between-nosubstitute-and-cooper).

Comment: Just a heads-up. The answer by @Cooper (with a manually typed array as the const data) runs fine by itself, but when I try to combine it with my *return* it doesn't work.

I'm thinking there's either a mistake in my combination of our code, or it's simply not compatible with my return.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final answer, but part of the development of the question.
Since it was confusing for readers, I have moved it out into it's own answer.
The [proper and final answer is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72937522/8289545).

**ALRIGHT, I NOW HAVE COME MUCH CLOSER TO A RESULT I LIKE!**

Now all the data is listed in columns.
I borrowed some formatting suggestions from here, with a for-loop inside the array idea from another place to make the data display in a table, which probably can be done in several different nicer ways.
Maybe even a way that will keep the alignment correct?

This the current js.

```js
document.getElementById("btnserno2").addEventListener("click",fetchCBS);
    function fetchCBS(){
//This clears the results between searches. Else the html+= below will keep adding rows of data at the bottom.
        document.getElementById("idCBS").innerHTML = "";

        var sernum = document.getElementById("serial2").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(printCBS)
        .queryCBS(sernum);
        document.getElementById("serial2").value = "";
    }

    window.printCBS = function(CBS) {
    console.log(CBS);
    
    var i,innerArray;
    var L = CBS[0].length;
  
    for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    innerArray = CBS[0][i];
  
    value1 = innerArray[0]; 
    value2 = innerArray[1];
    value3 = innerArray[2];
  
    console.log(value1 + "__" + value2 + "__" + value3)

// This creates the table in the idCBS spot.
// Both <table> and <tr> bits can be removed, and result is still the same.    

    let html='<style>td,th{border:0px solid black;}</style><table>';
    html+='<tr><td>' + value1 + '</td><td>' + value2 + '</td><td>' + value3 + '</td></tr>';
    html+='</table>';
    
    document.getElementById("idCBS").innerHTML += html;
  
    }
}

//Code for the clearResults button
document.getElementById("clearResults").addEventListener("click",clrResults);
function clrResults(){
    document.getElementById("idCBS").innerHTML = "";
}
```

It is displayed in page.html like this.

```html
    <h4>Results<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="clearResults">Clear Results</button></h4>
    
    <table class="striped">
        <tr>
            <td><h6>Serial</h6></td>
            <td><h6>Device OU</h6></td>
            <td><h6>Most Recent User</h6></td>
        </tr>
        <table id="idCBS">
        </table>
    </table>
```

This means I have the headers of the coming table visible before the search.
But, since I use two tables, the headers aren't responsive, and don't adjust to the width of the coming columns which have wider values.
It looks like this.

[image: CBL_headers_not_aligned]

If I try to put the headers inside the html+= creation loop in js, I of course get repeated headers.
If I instead put the headers inside the idCBS table on page they are wiped by the early document.getElementById("idCBS").innerHTML = "" command.

If I don't use  and instead choose either  or , then the data isn't looped properly, and is instead appended to the same row. Maybe I haven't tried all combinations, but I did try quite a few.

I'm guessing there is a better combination of js + html to display my data in a perfectly aligned table.